# Bibtex reference capitalisation concerning surname additions (van, van der, 't, etc)

Tags: bibtex, natbib, sorting, capitalization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bibtex handling of the Dutch “van” name prefix with natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40747/bibtex-handling-of-the-dutch-van-name-prefix-with-natbib)

In Dutch many people have a surname addition (Jan de Vries, Peter van Sluik), which are capitalized when the first name is not included.

- Yesterday I had beer with Jan de Vries.
- Yesterday I had beer with De Vries.

When sorting names alphabetically, the additions are not counted and put behind the first name.

- Jansen, Jaap
- Vries, Jan de

How do I make sure Bibtex handles this correctly?

I have tried the following:

1 author = "Jan de Vries",

2 author = "Jan De Vries",

3 author = "Jan {de Vries}",

4 author = "Jan {De Vries}",

With:

```
 @PREAMBLE{ "\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " 
          # "\newcommand{\singleletter}[1]{#1} " }
```

5 author = "Jan {\noopsort{Vries}}{de Vries}",

6 author = "Jan {\noopsort{Vries}}{De Vries}",

1 Correctly reads 'de' as a surname addition, but then doesn't capitalize it in text: *"I had beer with de Vries (2012)."*

2 Reads 'De' as second first name, hence ignores it in the text: *"I had beer with Vries (2012)."*, also it wrong capitalizes the addition in the references *(Vries, Jan De)*

3 Treats 'de Vries' as surname, not capitalizing it in the text, and sorting it wrongly in the references.

4 Treats 'De Vries' as surname, doest it well in the text (since one only references to something with his first name once, this is done with *"I had beer with Jan de Vries \citeyearp{Vries12}".* This is sorts the name wrongly in the references.

5 Prints the name wrongly in the text, sorts it well, but doesn't put 'de' behind the first name in the references: *"de Vries, Jan".*

6 This is the best soplution I've found. In text is okay, sorting is good, but the name order and capitalisation goes wrong in the references: *"De Vries, Jan"* which should be: *"Vries, Jan de"*

This boils down to the following question:

- **How can I make a distinction in bibtex between the name as it is used in text and as it is used in the references?**

(I had hoped the package babelbib would fix this language specific problem for me, but it doesn't.)

Comment: Would this answer help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40750/4427

Comment: You're an angel, egreg!
I'd wish I'd found that one myself.... 

Back to Google-fu school with me. ;)

Comment: I forgot to say "Welcome to TeX.SX!" It's not only Google-fu, I should admit: I gave that answer. `:)` Don't worry if your first question will be closed as duplicate: it will still be helpful to other readers.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. This solves it, mostly. I'd rather also have the option of putting the 'van' after the first name in the references. *"Vries, Jan de"*, the provided solution doesn't offer that. But this works well enough for now.

Comment: What bib style are you using?

Comment: ChigacoReedWeb, available here: http://web.reed.edu/cis/help/latex/bibtexstyles.html. A least, I think it's the same.

Comment: Write `author={{\VAN{De}{}}Vries, J. de},`

Comment: Thanks! That did exactly what it should! You're an angel and let no-one tell you different, kind sir.