# Differentiating multiple authors having same surname (last name)

Tags: bibtex, citing, acm

I am citing works of two authors, say, `K. Lee 2010` and `V. Lee 2010`. When I used `apacite` package, it took care of making sure that in the text if multiple authors have same surname then their first name is also used. However, now I am using ACM journal provided `bst` file which quotes both of them as `Lee 2010` and hence it becomes unclear.

I am using BibTeX (`biblatex` conflicts with journal provided format). I tried to search on google but could not find much except [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=13231). Can you tell how I should address this. Here is an MWE.

```
\documentclass[acmnow]{acmtrans2m}
\begin{document}
First is \cite{vlee2010}. Second is \cite{jlee2010}. 
\bibliographystyle{acmtrans}
\bibliography{temp}
\end{document}
```

Bibtex file is:

```
@inproceedings{vlee2010,
  title={{First paper}},
  author={Lee, VCCC and  others},
  booktitle={xyz}, 

  year={2010},

}
@inproceedings{jlee2010,
  title={{Second Paper}},
  author={Lee, JCCC and others},
  booktitle={pqr},  
  year={2010},  
}
```

The style and bst files used are: [style file](http://temp-share.com/show/f3Ygubqdn) and [bst file](http://temp-share.com/show/3YgF5c2Px)

Output comes:

```
First is [Lee et al. 2010b]. Second is [Lee et al. 2010a].
REFERENCES
Lee, J. et al. 2010a. Second Paper. In pqr.
Lee, V.  et al. 2010b. First paper. In xyz.
```

Comment: Please, always provide a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), even when it seems to you that it is not necessary.

Comment: To follow up on @tohecz's comment: Please provide an example that lists clearly which `.bst` file you use. If you use a citation management package such as `natbib` or `harvard`, please be sure to include this crucial bit of information as well.

Comment: Well, I'd says that's the journals problem. They provide the `.bst`, so that's what they what...

Comment: Can you point to the source of the class and the bst file?

Comment: I agree with Alex on this. If the journal provided the bst, then that's the format they want. Even if it isn't, you may end up spending a fair bit of time coming up with your own solution, only to find that the journal won't accept it. You should check with the journal before you spend any time guessing at what change, if any, they really require.

Comment: @egreg I have added them in question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose a variant of [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40750/4427).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{vlee2010,
  title={{First paper}},
  author={\disambiguate{Lee V}{V.}{Lee}, VCCC and  others},
  booktitle={xyz},

  year={2010},

}
@inproceedings{jlee2010,
  title={{Second Paper}},
  author={\disambiguate{Lee J}{J.}{Lee}, JCCC and others},
  booktitle={pqr},
  year={2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[acmnow]{acmtrans2m}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\disambiguate}[3]{#2~#3}


\begin{document}
First is \cite{vlee2010}. Second is \cite{jlee2010}.
\bibliographystyle{acmtrans}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\disambiguate}[3]{#3}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is only to make the document self-contained, you can do as usual with a separate `.bib` file.

The first argument to `\disambiguate` is ignored by LaTeX, but is used by BibTeX for sorting. Add whatever it's needed to ensure correct sorting. In the document proper we define `\disambiguate` to use the second and third arguments (initial and surname), while in the bibliography it will use only the surname.

[image]

Comment: +1, just it's likely it will be rejected by the journal typesetter :-/

Comment: @tohecz I will ask them to make sure.

Comment: Instructions for the picky typesetter: remove `#2~` from the first definition of `\disambiguate` and leave the rest as is.

Comment: @egreg Great idea!