# bibtex: citing authors with same surname

Tags: natbib, sorting

I'm working on a document where I need to cite work by two separate authors with the same surname but different first names (Stefan Müller and Gereon Müller). I've followed the instructions in [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100317/differentiating-multiple-authors-having-same-surname-last-name), and mostly everything goes fine: if I type `as \citet{gmueller98} shows`, I get "as G. Müller (1998) shows" in the main text and then "Müller, Gereon. 1998. [rest of bib entry]" in the bibliography, and similarly for `\citet{smueller03}`. The only thing that doesn't work is that, in the bibliography, both Müllers are alphabetized between Collins and Engel. See MWE below.

.tex file

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\disambiguate}[3]{#2~#3}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{gmueller98} mentions some of the data discussed in \citet{smueller03}. See also \citet{collins02} and \citet{engel70}.

\DeclareRobustCommand{\disambiguate}[3]{#1}
\bibliographystyle{spr-chicago}
\bibliography{mwe}

\end{document}
```

.bib file

```
@incollection{collins02,
Author = {Collins, Christopher},
Title = {{Eliminating labels}},
Booktitle = {{Derivation and explanation in the minimalist program}},
Editor = {Epstein, Samuel and Seely, Daniel},
Publisher = {Blackwell},
Address = {Oxford},
Pages = {42--64},
Year = {2002}}

@book{engel70,
Author = {Engel, Ulrich},
Title = {{Regeln zur Wortstellung}},
Publisher = {Institut f\"ur deutsche Sprache},
Address = {Mannheim},
Year = {1970}}

@book{gmueller98,
Author = {\disambiguate{M\"uller, Gereon}{G.}{M\"uller}},
Title = {{Incomplete category fronting}},
Publisher = {Kluwer},
Address = {Dordrecht},
Year = {1998}}

@article{smueller03,
Author = {\disambiguate{M\"uller, Stefan}{S.}{M\"uller}},
Title = {{Mehrfache Vorfeldbesetzung}},
Journal = {Deutsche Sprache},
Volume = {31},
Number = {1},
Pages = {29--62},
Year = {2003}}
```

Output:[image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an extra level of brackets around the `\disambiguate...` in the author field:

```
Author = {{\disambiguate{M\"uller, Gereon}{G.}{M\"uller}}},
```

This makes `bibtex` think `\disambiguate` is some sort of accent and so ignores it for sorting purposes.  Compare with the discussion of `\noopsort` in the [`bibtex` documentation "Using BibTeX"](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex).

[image: Sample output]

By the way I prefer `etoolbox`s mechanism for dealing with robust commands, as it provides a way to renew them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newrobustcmd{\disambiguate}[3]{#2~#3}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{gmueller98} mentions some of the data discussed in
\citet{smueller03}. See also \citet{collins02} and \citet{engel70}.

\renewrobustcmd{\disambiguate}[3]{#1}
\bibliographystyle{spr-chicago}
\bibliography{mwe}

\end{document}
```

`mwe.bib`:

```
@incollection{collins02,
Author = {Collins, Christopher},
Title = {{Eliminating labels}},
Booktitle = {{Derivation and explanation in the minimalist program}},
Editor = {Epstein, Samuel and Seely, Daniel},
Publisher = {Blackwell},
Address = {Oxford},
Pages = {42--64},
Year = {2002}}

@book{engel70,
Author = {Engel, Ulrich},
Title = {{Regeln zur Wortstellung}},
Publisher = {Institut f\"ur deutsche Sprache},
Address = {Mannheim},
Year = {1970}}

@book{gmueller98,
Author = {{\disambiguate{M\"uller, Gereon}{G.}{M\"uller}}},
Title = {{Incomplete category fronting}},
Publisher = {Kluwer},
Address = {Dordrecht},
Year = {1998}}

@Article{smueller03,
  author =   {{\disambiguate{M\"uller, Stefan}{S.}{M\"uller}}},
  title =    {{Mehrfache Vorfeldbesetzung}},
  journal =  {Deutsche Sprache},
  volume =   31,
  number =   1,
  pages =    {29--62},
  year =     2003
}
```