# Cite multiple authors with same surname using Biblatex' numeric style

Tags: biblatex

I would like to cite multiple authors with the same surname, such that calling `\textcite{<key>}` prints the author's initials if the surname is ambiguous i.e. in the minimum working example

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX engine = xelatex

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{german}

\usepackage[autostyle,
            english=british]{csquotes}
% BibLaTex
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./references.bib}


\begin{document}
  I want to cite \textcite{Robinson1959} and \textcite{Robinson1951}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

using the bibliography

```
@Article{Robinson1959,
  author     = {Julia Robinson},
  title      = {The undecidability of algebraic rings and fields},
  journal    = {Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.},
  year       = {1959},
  volume     = {10},
  number     = {6},
  pages      = {950--957},
  month      = {jun},
  issn       = {0002-9939},
  publisher  = {American Mathematical Society ({AMS})},
  fjournal   = {Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society},
  mrclass    = {02.00},
  mrnumber   = {0112842},
  mrreviewer = {R. M. Martin},
}

@Article{Robinson1951,
  author     = {Raphael M. Robinson},
  title      = {Arithmetical definability of field elements},
  journal    = {J. Symbolic Logic},
  year       = {1951},
  volume     = {16},
  number     = {02},
  pages      = {125--126},
  month      = {jun},
  issn       = {0022-4812},
  publisher  = {Cambridge University Press ({CUP})},
  fjournal   = {The Journal of Symbolic Logic},
  mrclass    = {02.0X},
  mrnumber   = {0042357},
  mrreviewer = {P. Lorenzen},
}
```

I would like `\textcite{Robinson1959}` to print `J. Robinson [1]` and `\textcite{Robinson1951}` to print `R. Robinson [2]`, or `R.M. Robinson [2]`. However, I currently get

[image: current output with ambiguous references]

I am aware of the solutions to these questions [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208222/bibtex-citing-authors-with-same-surname), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100317/differentiating-multiple-authors-having-same-surname-last-name). However, both of these solutions

1. modify the Bib-database which I would like to keep as is (I am accessing a centralised database) and
2. are built with Bibtex and LaTeX in mind (I am using Biblatex with Biber and XeLaTeX).

I also know that the [`apa`-style](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa?lang=en) has this behaviour automatically. So I am pretty sure that one should be able to achieve this using some kind of `\ateverybibitem` makro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `uniquename` option. Essentially you want the inverse of [biblatex, authoryear style: In-text citations display first name initials for certain bibliography entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864) and [Literature with Biber generates strange citations: firstnames appear erratically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91225/35864).

The option can take several values, the most natural setting in my eyes is `uniquename=full`. See page 63 and §4.11.4 *Name Disambiguation* (pp. 281-284) of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for other possible values and more details.

With the standard styles only the `uniquename` option is required, everything else is taken care of automatically.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[german,british]{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,uniquename= full]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Robinson1959,
  author     = {Julia Robinson},
  title      = {The undecidability of algebraic rings and fields},
  journal    = {Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.},
  year       = {1959},
  volume     = {10},
  number     = {6},
  pages      = {950--957},
  month      = jun,
  issn       = {0002-9939},
  publisher  = {American Mathematical Society ({AMS})},
  fjournal   = {Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society},
  mrclass    = {02.00},
  mrnumber   = {0112842},
  mrreviewer = {R. M. Martin},
}

@Article{Robinson1951,
  author     = {Raphael M. Robinson},
  title      = {Arithmetical definability of field elements},
  journal    = {J. Symbolic Logic},
  year       = {1951},
  volume     = {16},
  number     = {02},
  pages      = {125--126},
  month      = jun,
  issn       = {0022-4812},
  publisher  = {Cambridge University Press ({CUP})},
  fjournal   = {The Journal of Symbolic Logic},
  mrclass    = {02.0X},
  mrnumber   = {0042357},
  mrreviewer = {P. Lorenzen},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  I want to cite \textcite{Robinson1959} and \textcite{Robinson1951}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

> I want to cite J. Robinson [1] and R. M. Robinson [2].

Note that you should write `month = jun,` and not `month = {jun},`. Technically speaking the three-letter month abbreviations are realised as `@string`s and `@string`s must be addressed without braces. With `biblatex` it would be even nicer to use `date = {1959-06},` instead of `year = {1959}, month = jun,` but for backwards compatibility with traditional `.bst` styles the `month`/`year` combination has its merits.