# Latex citations Bibtex. Wrong capital and alphabetical order

Tags: bibtex, sorting

In my bibliography citations are ordered wrong. For example:

```
@inproceedings{17Degroot,
  title={Critical scour: new bed protection design method},
  author={De Groot, M.B.},
  booktitle={Journal of Hydraulic Engineering},
  volume={114},
  pages={1227--1240},
  year={1988},
  publisher={ASCE, New York, USA}
}
```

In my bibliography may it should say M.B. de Groot (no capital D) and in my report, it should refer to it as `[De Groot, 1988]` (Capital D). Besides this, the alphabetical order in the bibliography is wrong. Bibtex sorts this on the D while it should be on the `G`. I have the same problem with many other authors with prepositions.

I am using the `plainnat` bibliography style.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40747/bibtex-handling-of-the-dutch-van-name-prefix-with-natbib Please, look at the linked question that shows a problem very similar to yours.

Answer (score 5):

How does the author in the citation spell their name? If it's with a capital "D" then that's the way it should appear in the bibliography. However, you need to use a little trick to get `bibtex` to treat the "De" part as a prefix:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{17Degroot,
  title={Critical scour: new bed protection design method},
  author={{\uppercase{d}e} Groot, M.B.},
  booktitle={Journal of Hydraulic Engineering},
  volume={114},
  pages={1227--1240},
  year={1988},
  publisher={ASCE, New York, USA}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Text cite: \citet{17Degroot}
Parenthetical cite: \citep{17Degroot}.

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

If the author spells their name with a lower case "d" then that's the way it should appear in the text, unless the citation starts a sentence.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{17Degroot,
  title={Critical scour: new bed protection design method},
  author={de Groot, M.B.},
  booktitle={Journal of Hydraulic Engineering},
  volume={114},
  pages={1227--1240},
  year={1988},
  publisher={ASCE, New York, USA}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

Text cite: \citet{17Degroot}
Parenthetical cite: \citep{17Degroot}.

\Citet{17Degroot} blah blah.

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Here's how to sort on "G" rather than "d":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\newcommand*{\swap}[2]{#2#1}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{17Degroot,
  title={Critical scour: new bed protection design method},
  author={{\swap{Groot}{de }}, M.B.},
  booktitle={Journal of Hydraulic Engineering},
  volume={114},
  pages={1227--1240},
  year={1988},
  publisher={ASCE, New York, USA}
}

@inproceedings{Gadzooks,
 title={Sample},
 author={A. Gadzooks},
 booktitle={Blah},
 year=2013
}

@inproceedings{Grunt,
 title={Sample},
 author={A. Grunt},
 booktitle={Blah},
 year=2013
}

@inproceedings{Datone,
 title={Sample},
 author={A. Dat-one},
 booktitle={Blah some more},
 year=2013
}

@inproceedings{Disone,
 title={Sample},
 author={A. Dis-one},
 booktitle={Blah some more},
 year=2013
}

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\Citet{17Degroot} blah blah.
\Citep{17Degroot}.

\cite{*}

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of result]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried the first option you gave me. Bibtex did still sorts it alphabetically on the D. If i put it like `author={Groot, M.B. de},` it will be correct but in the text it will ofcourse only say `Groot` now. Besides this my University demands a prefixs in texts are with a Capital. So in the text it should be `De Groot, 1988` and in the bibliography as `M.B. de Groot`.

Comment: @Hans-Peter Then I suggest you put `author={M. B. de Groot}` in the bib file and just remember to cite it using `\Citet` or `\Citep`.

Comment: in this way the alphabetical order is still incorrect and in the text it is still with no capital D.

Comment: @Hans-Peter I've added an example that sorts on "G" rather than "d".

Answer (score 2):

I understand that disregarding the "von" component of an author's name for purposes of sorting is common in Dutch -- where possibly half the population have either "de" or "van" in their names. (OK, this may be an exaggeration...) It's actually not difficult to modify the `plainnat` bibliography style to implement the "Dutch" sorting style. Modifying the bibliography stye file would spare you the task of hand-editing (possibly lots and lots of) `author` fields in your `.bib` file.

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file, and call the copy (say) `myplainnat.bst`. (Do not edit an original file.)
- Open `myplainnat.bst` in your favorite text editor.
- Locate the function `sort.format.names`. (It starts on line 1207 in my copy of `plainnat.bst`.) In that function, locate the following line:

  ```
        s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Change this line to:

  ```
        s nameptr "{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  Even if you're entirely unfamiliar with BibTeX's syntax, I think you should be able to tell what's going on: the sorting will now only include the author's surname, followed by any first name(s), followed by any "junior" component.
- Save the file `myplainnat.bst` either in the same directory as your main `.tex` file or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you use the latter method, be sure to update the TeX distribution's filename database.
- Start using the new bibliography style by issuing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}` in your `.tex` file(s).

Nicola Talbot, in her answer to your posting, has already mentioned how to get *citations* that include a lowercase "von" part to start with an uppercase letter: use the `\Citet` and `\Citep` citation commands (rather than `\citet` and `\citep`).

Happy BibTeXing!