# Handling the nobility particle in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, bibdesk

The surnames with a nobility particle (e.g. "de Sample", or "van Sample") are being listed in the bibliography in the alphabetical order by the first letter of the particle (e.g. "van Sample" is listed under "v"). I want it instead to be listed under the first letter of the surname ("van Sample" listed under "s").

I'm using `BibDesk` reference management software, and `natbib` package. The bibliography style I'm using is [phil_review](http://tedsider.org/latex/phil_review.bst)). Modifying the .bib file directly as in [Latex citations Bibtex. Wrong capital and alphabetical order](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108325/latex-citations-bibtex-wrong-capital-and-alphabetical-order/108375#108375) doesn't provide the correct result for me.

Comment: A simple little trick is the `\noop` one. See, e.g., [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160195/8528). Basically: define `\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}`; then add `\noop{Sample}` to the start of an author field to get it to sort under 'Sample'.

Comment: If you're required to use `phil_review.bst` for a submission, you shouldn't worry.

Comment: @jon this does reorganize it -- it's no longer stored under 'v', but oddly it doesn't store it under 's' either, rather between 'm' and 'p', oddly.

Comment: @bozidarka -- That is odd; but I can't help without a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) to experiment with. egreg's point is also worth considering: it may well be that the creator of `phil_review.bst` or the journal that relies on it has strong, prescriptive ideas about how to sort the 'von-part' names.

Comment: In case this is useful for someone: I had problems getting BibTeX to alphabetize properly "d'Aspremont", which it listed with the Ds rather than the As. Changing the author field to "d' Aspremont" (notice the extra space) put it at the right place, but the space was unwelcome. I finally found the following solution: make the author field "d' \unskip Aspremont". For the time being, this seems to have totally solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting another set of braces around `\noop{}` apparently solves the problem. So if I write:

```
  @article{Test,
        Author = {Test {\noop{Adams}} van Adams},
        Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:18:24 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:31:54 +0000},
        Journal = {Sample Journal},
        Title = {Sample Title},
        Year = {2015}}
```

the problem goes away, and the document compiles correctly. Not sure why without the braces the place it selects to put "van Adams" is between "m" and "p".

So where the test.bib is:

```
@article{V,
    Author = {Sample Voyt},
    Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:26:14 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:27:33 +0000},
    Journal = {Sample Journal},
    Title = {Sample Title},
    Year = {2014}}

@article{S,
    Author = {Sample Stewart},
    Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:25:29 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:28:33 +0000},
    Journal = {Sample Journal},
    Title = {Sample Title},
    Year = {2014}}

@article{P,
    Author = {Samlpe Peters},
    Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:21:11 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:24:23 +0000},
    Journal = {Sample Journal},
    Title = {Sample Title},
    Year = {2014}}

@article{M,
    Author = {Sample Matthews},
    Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:18:59 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:19:47 +0000},
    Journal = {Sample Journal},
    Title = {Sample Title},
    Year = {2015}}

  @article{Test,
        Author = {Test {\noop{Adams}} van Adams},
        Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:18:24 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:31:54 +0000},
        Journal = {Sample Journal},
        Title = {Sample Title},
        Year = {2015}}
```

and .tex file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}

\newcommand{\noop}[1]{}
\title{Sample}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{phil_review}
\bibliography{Test}{}
\end{document}
```

the outcome is as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MWE, that achieves that 'van Adams' is not stored under 'v', but for some reason not that it is stored under 'a':

Test.bib file just contains:

```
    @article{V,
        Author = {Sample Voyt},
        Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:26:14 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:27:33 +0000},
        Journal = {Sample Journal},
        Title = {Sample Title},
        Year = {2014}}

    @article{S,
        Author = {Sample Stewart},
        Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:25:29 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:28:33 +0000},
        Journal = {Sample Journal},
        Title = {Sample Title},
        Year = {2014}}

    @article{P,
        Author = {Samlpe Peters},
        Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:21:11 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:24:23 +0000},
        Journal = {Sample Journal},
        Title = {Sample Title},
        Year = {2014}}

    @article{M,
        Author = {Sample Matthews},
        Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:18:59 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:19:47 +0000},
        Journal = {Sample Journal},
        Title = {Sample Title},
        Year = {2015}}

    @article{Test,
        Author = {Test \noop{Adams} van Adams},
        Date-Added = {2015-02-20 20:18:24 +0000},
        Date-Modified = {2015-02-20 20:31:54 +0000},
        Journal = {Sample Journal},
        Title = {Sample Title},
        Year = {2015}}
```

.tex file is as follows:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[american]{babel}
    \usepackage{natbib}

    \newcommand{\noop}[1]{}
    \title{Sample}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliographystyle{phil_review}
    \bibliography{Test}{}
    \end{document}
```

Though this will not list "van Adams" under "v", it will not list it under "a" either; rather between "m" and "p".

Comment: You need to use a canonical name format for names with a von part. In BibTeX, this is "von Last, First, Jr" (you'll see this is BibDesk's author/editor list). Fix that, and then see if you still have a sort issue. If so, http://kaivonfintel.org/von/ may help.

Comment: The issue is independent of the canonical name format. But http://kaivonfintel.org/von/ solution seems to work.

Comment: Your example code won't list `Test \noop{Adams} van Adams` under "A" because BibTeX interprets the first "Adams" as being part of the name's first-name component. Try `\noop{adams}` instead (note the lowercase "a").

Comment: @Mico even when I use `\noop{adams}` and list the name in a canonical formant, it's still listed between 'm' and 'p'. But, the suggestion here: http://kaivonfintel.org/von/ does the trick.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered; you can get away with this form since you have a lowercase v in the von part. Incidentally, [btxdoc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) documents the name splitting behavior and sorting workarounds. *edit* My comment above has the Jr token in the wrong place, as I wrote that from memory.