# Bibtex and abbrv.bst: List as "A. van Surname", sort under "S" in bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Using the `abbrv.bst`, is it possible to get a bibtex entry like

```
@article{Surname,
 author = {Surname, Author van},
 title = {Title},    
 journal = {Journal},
 year = {2016}
 }
```

typeset as `A. van Surname. Title. Journal. 2016.`, but sorted under the first letter of the surname, rather than "V" for "van"?

Comment: Is [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40747/bibtex-handling-of-the-dutch-van-name-prefix-with-natbib) suitable for you?

Comment: Yes, yes it does! Thank you!
In fact, as I have less requirements, I can make due with `\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[2]{#2}` before the `\bibliography{bib}` and `{\VAN{Surname}{van}}` in the bibtex file.