# Sorting Dutch surnames with 'van' and 'van der' in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style, sorting

In my document I use `natbib` package with `apalike` style. I really enjoy the citation style and would prefer not to change anything. However, there is a small issue: Dutch second names with **van** and **van der** appear in Bibliography with second names starting with **V**. For example, **von Wright** is a neighbour of **Vardi** in bibliography. Is there any way to have it sorted by the main part of second name? So that **von Wright** will appear together with **Walter**, rather than **Vardi**. Cheers!

Comment: What about names that contain `de` (as in, say, Casper de Vries or Kevin de Bruyne)? Should they be sorted under D (for "de") or (here) V or B, respectively? Please advise.

Comment: Under V and B. Ideally, I would like to have second names sorted by capitalised part of the name with van\van der\de, etc. preserved. E.g. ... Bruegel, P. <reference>; de Bruyne, K. <reference>

Comment: The answer I just posted modifies BibTeX's sorting method, so that it sorts first by surname and only then on the "von" component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Locate the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apalike-nl.bst`. (You're obviously free to select another file name.)
- Open the file `apalike-nl.bst` in a text editor; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Locate the function `sort.format.names` in the bst file. (In my copy of this file, this function starts on line 914.)
- In this function, locate the following line:

  ```
        s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't := % <= here
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
        s nameptr "{ll{ }}{vv{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
  ```

  I trust you can guess what the `ll` and `vv` components of a full name denote.
- Save the file `apalike-nl.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution appropriately.
- In the main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apalike}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apalike-nl}
  ```

  and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice* more to fully propagate the change.

Happy BibTeXing!

---

Here's a minimal working example (MWE). Observe that "van Bronckhorst" is listed before "de Bruyne"; with the standard version of `apalike`, "de Bruyne" would come before "van Bronckhorst".

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{kdb, author="Kevin de Bruyne", title="Thoughts", year=2018}
@misc{gvb, author="Giovanni van Bronckhorst", title="Thoughts", year=2018}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-nl}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

No need to change the bibliography style; recycling https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40750/4427 should work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{vannoort,
  author={{\VAN{Noort}{Van}{van}} Noort, Thomas},
  title={An important paper},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2010,
}
@article{kdb,
  author={{\VAN{Bruyne}{De}{de}} Bruyne, Kevin},
  title={Thoughts},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2018,
}
@article{gvb,
  author={{\VAN{Bronckhorst}{Van}{van}} Bronckhorst, Giovanni},
  title={Thoughts},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2018,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% #1: sorting key, #2: prefix for citation, #3: prefix for bibliography
\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[3]{#2} % set up for citation

\begin{document}

\citet{vannoort}
\citet{kdb}
\citet{gvb}

% here we change the meaning of \VAN to use the prefix for the bibliography
\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[3]{#3}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need to uppercase “Van” or “De”, you can just set

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\VAN}[3]{#3}
```

in the preamble and comment out the second setting. One could also go with just two arguments, but being redundant can save later troubles.

With the change one gets

[image]

Comment: It might be useful, for casual readers of this posting, if you pointed out *explicitly* that even though the approach proposed in your answer requires more work up front, compared with making a copy of a bst file and modifying a single line in the new bibliography style file, it has the following considerable advantage: It is compatible with *any* bibliography style, not just `apalike`. Put differently, simply by changing the definition of `\VAN`, one can go back and forth between including and not including the von-component of an author's name in the sorting process.